# How to plot graph when data lies in every alternate column in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, graph

How do i plot graphs when the data that i want to plot lies on every alternate column? I tried to use the below code but it gives me two empty graph which im not sure which part of my codes am i missing out or done wrong. If done correctly, it should be graphs something like the one shown in "expected output".

Edited:

The X values are in the 1st column while the y values are 2,4,6,8 etc..

data use for plotting

[image]

Expected output

[image]

```
Sub plotgraph()


 Dim i As Long, c As Long
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim Cht As Chart
    Dim rngDB As Range, rngX As Range
    Dim Srs As Series
    Dim ws As Worksheet

     Set ws = Sheets("Data")

    Set rngDB = ws.UsedRange

    c = rngDB.Columns.Count
 Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddChart
Set Cht = shp.Chart

    With Cht
        For i = 1 To c Step 2 'For every alternate column so in step2
            With ws
                Set rngX = ws.Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(2, i).End(xlDown))

            End With

        Set Srs = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            With Srs
                .XValues = rngX
            End With
        Next i

     ws.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    Cht.ChartType = xlXYScatter
'    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Data!$A:$A")
    Cht.Axes(xlValue).Select
    Cht.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 6.45
    Cht.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 5
    Cht.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 6.8
    Cht.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 9

         Cht.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.00E+00"
        Cht.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        Cht.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
End With

End Sub
```

Issue

[image]

Comment: Where are your X values though?

Comment: @TimWilliams ah sorry about that, i have included the X values in my updated post, the part that is  With Srs   .XValues = rngX End With

Comment: @Timwilliams but still no output tho..

Comment: @TimWilliams btw is Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddChart necessary tho? Because when i tried record the macro and plot the graph, it doesn't include this..

Comment: Still not seeing any x-values.  In your "expected" plots the worksheet data = y-values  Where are the x-values (201751 etc) ?   What are you plotting those mA values against?

Comment: @TimWilliams i think you mean the x values data in my excel? I shown it in my updated post and yeah i think have forgotton to include x values data in it

Comment: @TimWilliams ok so when plotting the graph, i am supposed to use the same x values which is in 1st column and alternating columns of y values to  plot different graphs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub plotgraphs()


    Dim i As Long, c As Long
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim Cht As Chart, co As Shape
    Dim rngDB As Range, rngX As Range, rngY As Range
    Dim Srs As Series
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Data")

    Set rngDB = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    Set rngX = rngDB.Columns(1)
    Set rngY = rngDB.Columns(2)

    Do While Application.CountA(rngY) > 0

        Set co = ws.Shapes.AddChart
        Set Cht = co.Chart

        With Cht
            .ChartType = xlXYScatter
            'remove any data which might have been
            '  picked up when adding the chart
            Do While .SeriesCollection.Count > 0
                .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
            Loop
            'add the data
            With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries()
                .XValues = rngX.Value
                .Values = rngY.Value
            End With
            'formatting...
            With Cht.Axes(xlValue)
                .MinimumScale = 5
                .MaximumScale = 9
                .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.00E+00"
            End With
            Cht.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            Cht.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        End With

        Set rngY = rngY.Offset(0, 2) 'next y values
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: for some reasons, the 2nd graph didn't appear. Anyways, does this code works for more than 2 y alternating column data as well

Comment: Works fine for me - the plots will be stacked so you'll need to add code to position them.

Comment: i posted the output that i am having currently in my updated post so that you can see whether did i miss out anything..

Comment: Looks like the y-axis max/min settings are hiding your points.  Change those as needed.

Comment: ah my bad, i went to make my y axis fix just now. Now it works as intended. Thanks alot..